# Play Framework, Ebean and Akka Promises

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, akka, ebean

We are studying to use Play! Framework in a new project. We picked Play! because of it's productivity, Scala support and non-blocking architecture.

After stress testing the (Java) Computer-database sample application I saw a lot of dispatcher and Ebean threads and I couldn't find out how Play integrates with Ebean ORM. Every call is dispatched to Akka and executed in another thread.

I read all Play! framework documentation (specially this part http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaAsync) and couldn't find any information about how this integration work.

I'll really appreciate if someone could light this path for us.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first of all, about benchmarking:

please read this page about production setup: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/Production it's crucial to have the right akka settings before running any benchmarks (depending on whether your app is mainly a blocking or non-blocking app you may need to use different threading settings). Also, please make sure you only benchmark in prod mode.

As for ebean: play is using the ebean library as is (including running ebean's bytecode enhancer), so there is nothing special about it. Generally speaking, each request gets a separate thread and we send the response through akka to netty asynchronously.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok... If every request is dispatched to Akka, and will never block, why do we need _Asynchronous Results_?

I thought Play! would block if I do some computing intensive task or some heavy query to database.

About benchmarking: I was running the application with `play start` and did some fine tunning acoording to this post: http://www.jamesward.com/2012/06/25/optimizing-play-2-for-database-driven-apps

Comment: @poko I'm also interested about this. Do you think you can please answer?